# API или Прямое подключение ?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

Всем привет! Делаю первое Андроид приложение и задался вопросом как лучше реализовывать подключение к базе данных ?? Написать свое апи на стороне сервера и обращаться путем запросов или же напрямую настроить подключение к базе данных в приложении ? Что будет работать быстрее ? И какие есть подводные камни ?

Comment: Если Вы будете к базе обращаться из приложения, то придется в приложении хардкодить логин и пароль что понижает безопасность в целом.  Разница в скорости между Вашими вариантами не существенна

Comment: Разница по скорости скорее всего будет, если API запилить, тогда подключений к базе будет максимум 10, а без на каждого пользователя что приведет к падениям скорости при локах базы, а когда количество пользователей превысить максимальное число, тогда для новых не будет ресурсов

Answer (score 3):

**API.**
Доступен только тот функционал, который заложил автор.
Проблемы безопасности автор решает также сам, в том числе и "корявые" api-запросы, и уровень доступа для пользователей.
Вес приложения использующее API, по логике меньше, т.к. драйвер СУБД может требовать установленного клиента самой СУБД.
Возможность использовать кэш вэб-сервера, если подразумевается подобная архитектура.

**СУБД**
Доступ происходит напрямую в СУБД, следовательно, в приложении "где-то" лежит реквизиты доступа, со всеми из этого вытекающими последствиями. Даже если выданы привилегии пользователям только(!) SELECT, ни что не мешает "ободрать" контент ресурса, а пара умышленных тяжелых запросов подвесит вашу СУБД на продолжительное время.
Как говорилось выше,приложение под Android может затребовать драйвер СУБД, которого просто может не существовать, как и клиента.